# How to make the arrow more natural?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, decorations

I have no idea to put the arrow into natural way.
The source code is like the below

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [decorate,decoration={coil,segment length=7.2mm,aspect=1,amplitude=2mm},->,>=stealth] (2,1.7)--(3,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: sample image of arrow]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you elaborate, what you mind with "more natural way"? And, please, provide complete, small document, which we can copy and compile.

Comment: I think in this case a sample image would help as well.

Comment: put some bacon on it :P

Comment: @percusse This is a serious platform. It is the wrong place for jokes like this. If you violate these rules furthermore, I will beat you up with ham until you are sensible.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz have some [Bacon](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/f/francisbac136014.html) :D

Comment: Are you thinking of the tail leaving the arrowhead on an awkward angle? I'm sure that's been addressed before.

Comment: Thank you Chris and Jesse. I don' t know how to delete my answer, so could someone delete the answer below?

Comment: Chris, that's what I wanted to say! Could you give the URL of the answer for this question?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways to do it:

- lower the aspect
- reduce the coil's length
- use post length to have some space before the arrow (not shown)

[image: solution]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  % ~~~ the problem ~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw [   decorate,
            decoration={coil,segment length=7.2mm,aspect=1,amplitude=2mm},
            -stealth]               (2, 1.7) -- ( 3, 0.5);

  % ~~~ for reference ~~~~~~~~
  \draw [-stealth]                  (2, 1.2) -- (3, 0);

  % ~~~ modified aspect ratio of spring ~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw [   decorate,
            decoration={coil,segment length=7.2mm,aspect=.9,amplitude=2mm},
            -stealth]               (2, 0.7) -- ( 3, -.5);

  % ~~~ coil reduced in length ~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw [   decorate,
            decoration={coil,segment length=7.0mm,aspect=1,amplitude=2mm},
            -stealth]               (2, 0.0) -- ( 3, -1.2);
            
    % ~~~ notes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node at ( 4.5, 0.5)    {the problem};
    \node at ( 4.5, 0)      {for reference};
    \node at ( 4.5, -.5)    {lower aspect};
    \node at ( 4.5, -1.2)   {reduced length};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```